# How can I define a method that can return the biggest variable in a array

Tags: java, arrays

Like the title how it can accepts   an  array   of  int and returns the largest value   from    the array

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Integer array[] = {1, 4, 3, 2};
int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));
System.out.println(max);
Output:
4
```